# How do I create a checklist in a slack message?

Tags: slack, formatting, markdown

I'm trying to create a task list for myself in a private chat with my supervisor on Slack. I'm pretty familiar with markdown, and I thought that Slack supported it too. On GitHub, you can create tasks lists by writing something like this.

```
 - [ ] uncompleted task
 - [x] completed task
```

I thought Slack supported checklists like that too, especially since there are references to "checklist formatting", for example

- https://www.kosmotime.com/slack-task-management/: *Use Slack’s built in features: Create a post with checklist formatting.*
- https://slack.com/intl/en-de/help/articles/224766507-To-do-lists-in-Slack-: *For a traditional to-do list, you can create a post with checklist formatting.*

Nowhere can I find any information on how that "checklist formatting" is done. When I search for "slack checklist formatting" on your favorite search engine, all I get is generic articles on how to format posts, that don't mention anything about checklists. When I try the GitHub formatting, it doesn't show up as actual checkboxes.

Please send help.

Answer (score 9):

I found it! Wow I had this same issue -

Here's the thing. You have to 'Create a Post' using the lightening bolt - not by just typing it into slack. When you click on the lightening bolt, there's a post pop up box - you type in there and THEN one of the formatting options is the checklist.

So frustrating really - why not just have that a standard formatting option? Who ever clicks on the lightening bolt?

Anyhow, this article will give you more details - cheers

https://usefyi.com/how-to-keep-a-to-do-list-in-slack/

Comment: Create a Post is now in the "+" popup menu in at the bottom of your entry box

Comment: 1. Seems this is only available on web or desktop, not mobile?  2. Checklist is just one of the types of bulleted lists, so you create text first, then select it, then you can turn it into a checklist. 3. You can't see the actual checklist on mobile, you have to click through to see the post. 4. You can't check the list from the preview, either. 5. Can't even check things off on mobile if you open the post.

Comment: I can't seem to find any lightning bolts in the desktop app.   How the hell is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Slack integration that let's you create a checklist as a message in your conversations. Anyone in the channel can collaborate on the list as well. You can then pin and bookmark the message to make it easy to find. For a step by step guide you can visit https://www.workast.com/blog/how-to-create-a-checklist-on-slack/